# When i play a song in my ipod and when the screen of my ipod locks the song stops automatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I had created a music application and  my ipod is updated to OS4.0 .When i play song in ipod and after sometime when the screen of my ipod locks the song which is being played also stops automatically which is a problem.Please anybody help me in solving this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to handle the interruption in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483282/how-to-handle-the-interruption-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer I just posted here:

[how to handle the interruption in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483282/how-to-handle-the-interruption-in-iphone/3483553#3483553)